# getElementsByTagName not working with 'p' (paragraph)

Tags: php, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to get the content inside the div called 'item-page'. The html comes from a curl session and it's contained in the $html variable. I'm using getElementsByTagName but it only works with 'div' as value in the (), if I put 'p' it doesn't work. Does anyone know why?

Here it's the code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$div = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach ($div as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') === 'item-page') {
       echo $tag->nodeValue."<br>"; 
    }
}
```

Here it's the html source (one the paragraph I should echo) from the website:

```
<div class="item-page"> 
<p> Chiusura dell'Istituto per gioved&igrave; 8 dicembre 2016 </p>
</div>
```

(The reason I am using the 'p' is because I can start a new line for each paragraph, if I use the 'div' it's showed as a single block).

Comment: How cant the `p` tag have the attribute `class` if only the `div` has it?

Comment: *"it doesn't work"*: could you explain what that means?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the P programming language, please do not use the [tag:p] tag.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the 'p' element on your page doesn't have the class 'item-page' like your code is expected. If you remove that if statement it will work how you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

if it works with 'div' but not with 'p', this means that $html doesn't contain p elements with class item-page

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code:

```
<?php
$html = "<div class=\"item-page\"> 
<p> Chiusura dell'Istituto per gioved&igrave; 8 dicembre 2016 </p>
</div>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$div = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

var_dump($div[0]);
die();

foreach ($div as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') === 'item-page') {
        echo $tag->nodeValue."<br>";
    }
}
```

and i'm getting the response i expect:

```
object(DOMElement) #3 (18) { ["tagName"]= > string(1)
"p" ["schemaTypeInfo"] => NULL["nodeName"] => string(1)
"p" ["nodeValue"] => string(53)
" Chiusura dell'Istituto per giovedì 8 dicembre 2016 " ["nodeType"] => int(1)["parentNode"] => string(22)
"(object value omitted)" ["childNodes"] => string(22)
"(object value omitted)" ["firstChild"] => string(22)
"(object value omitted)" ["lastChild"] => string(22)
"(object value omitted)" ["previousSibling"] => string(22)
"(object value omitted)" ["nextSibling"] => string(22)
"(object value omitted)" ["attributes"] => string(22)
"(object value omitted)" ["ownerDocument"] => string(22)
"(object value omitted)" ["namespaceURI"] => NULL["prefix"] => string(0)
"" ["localName"] => string(1)
"p" ["baseURI"] => NULL["textContent"] => string(53)
" Chiusura dell'Istituto per giovedì 8 dicembre 2016 "
}
```

Note that according to documentation, getElementByTagName returns a list

Answer (score 0):

Remove `p` from `$dom->getElementsByTagName()` and add `div` so your result shows all div's on page.

```
<?php 

$html = <<<EOT

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="item-page">
<p> Chiusura dell'Istituto per gioved&igrave; 8 dicembre 2016 </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>

EOT;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$div = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach ($div as $tag) {
    if ($tag->getAttribute('class') === 'item-page') {
       echo $tag->nodeValue."<br>"; 
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Chiusura dell'Istituto per giovedì 8 dicembre 2016
```